# How to open android browser with multiple tabs?

Tags: android, browser, android-activity, android-intent

I'm trying to open more than one link in different tabs in default android browser.

```
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url1));
startActivity(browserIntent);

browserIntent.setData(Uri.parse(url2));
startActivity(browserIntent);
```

Code above opens browser with one tab and reload it after calling each `startActivity(browserIntent)`. Is it any possibility to open new tab for each url and how it can be achieved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is it any possibility to open new tab for each url and how it can be achieved?

No.

For starters, the user's default browser might not even *have* tabs. Even if the device happens to have a tabbed browser pre-installed, the user is welcome to download a third-party browser app that happens to not have tabs, and make that their default browser.

Comment: I know that it's possible to not have tabs, but every android browser i;ve ever seen has tabs, including the AOSP one.

Comment: @IanNewson: That definitely was not the case in 2012, when this answer was written. Regardless, there is no standard `Intent` protocol to tell a third-party browser to open multiple links in multiple tabs.

Answer (score -2):

The android browser does have tabs. When your phone is loading a web page push on the button next to the link your loading or scroll all the way up on a page your already on and push it. It will open another tab window.